# Convert MusicTimeStamp (AudioToolbox) to Milliseconds

Tags: ios, audiotoolbox, mikmidi

I am using the [MIKMIDI](https://github.com/mixedinkey-opensource/MIKMIDI) framework and this is using the [AudioToolbox](https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiotoolbox/musictimestamp) type `MusicTimeStamp`

**How can i convert this timestamp to milliseconds?**

Comment: Multiply by 1000?

Comment: nope, it seems to be timeunit beats.. or something like that

Comment: See `MusicSequenceGetSecondsForBeats`.

Comment: okay, so am not able to convert it without the context of a music sequence?

Comment: Correct, you need a sequence because it takes tempo into account. Also, it's the time associated with the musical beat (so the time from the start of playback).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MusicTimeStamp` is a raw beat count, you need to know the tempo (and tempo map, tempo isn't an invariant) of the music you're working with in order to convert this into milliseconds.

Outside of a `MusicSequence` a MTS can't be mapped to a wall time.

*Edit:* A CoreMedia `CMTime` can be converted to wall times if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

There's new API for this in MIKMIDI. It's in a branch ([`1.8`](https://github.com/mixedinkey-opensource/MIKMIDI/pull/270)) as I write this, but should be merged soon, and released in the 1.8 release. It makes it much easier to do the conversion you're asking about.

In the context of a sequence, do:

```swift
let seconds = sequence.timeInSeconds(forMusicTimeStamp: musicTimeStamp)
```

There's also a method to convert in the opposite direction. `MIKMIDISequencer` has very similar, but more sophisticated (to account for looping, tempo override, etc.) methods to do the same kinds of conversions.

Without this new API in MIKMIDI, you can still use `MusicSequenceGetSecondsForBeats()`. You can get the underlying `MusicSequence` for an `MIKMIDISequence` using its `musicSequence` property:

```swift
var timeInSeconds = Float64(0)
MusicSequenceGetSecondsForBeats(sequence, musicTimeStamp, &timeInSeconds)
```

As far as I know this doesn't take into account looping even if you're doing it with the `MusicPlayer` API, and certainly not an overridden tempo if one is set on `MIKMIDISequencer`, so you should prefer MIKMIDI's API above if possible.